# how to inject an Id in the header for all GraphQL request. For example, In header for all GraphQL request it should come like:- Id:1234

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, graphql, apollo

How to inject an Id in the header for all GraphQL request.
For all GraphQL request in header it should come like:- Id:1234.I went through documentation of apollo GraphQL and many other stuff but felt the information is insufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at the [Apollo Authentication Example](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/recipes/authentication.html#Header). They set an authorization header. The same way you could set a different header.

The trick is to use `apollo-link-context` and concat it to your HTTP link.